# ¿Cómo puedo añadir las etiquetas de valores a este gráfico de barras apiladas?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
%matplotlib inline
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

X = pd.read_csv(r'C:Path.csv', encoding='latin1')

IDNivelEducativo_Programas = X.groupby(['ID_Nivel_Educativo','Programas_Conocidos']).size()

IDNivelEducativo_Programas = IDNivelEducativo_Programas.reset_index()

IDNivelEducativo_Programas = pd.pivot_table(IDNivelEducativo_Programas, columns = 'ID_Nivel_Educativo', index = 'Programas_Conocidos', values = 0)

IDNivelEducativo_Programas.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)
```

Y el resultado es este gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe cómo añadir los rótulos de valores numéricos para cada color en cada barra? Agradezco cualquier ayuda :D

Answer (score 0):

No es mi código, pero te podría servir esta función, que permite usar los valores y ubicarlos encima de cada barra:

```
def add_value_labels(ax, spacing=5):
"""(Not my code) Add labels to the end of each bar in a bar chart.

Arguments:
    ax (matplotlib.axes.Axes): The matplotlib object containing the axes
        of the plot to annotate.
    spacing (int): The distance between the labels and the bars.
"""

# For each bar: Place a label
for rect in ax.patches:
    # Get X and Y placement of label from rect.
    y_value = rect.get_height()
    x_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2

    # Number of points between bar and label. Change to your liking.
    space = spacing
    # Vertical alignment for positive values
    va = 'bottom'

    # If value of bar is negative: Place label below bar
    if y_value < 0:
        # Invert space to place label below
        space *= -1
        # Vertically align label at top
        va = 'top'

    # Use Y value as label and format number with zero decimal place
    label = "{:.0f}".format(y_value)

    # Create annotation
    ax.annotate(
        label,                      # Use `label` as label
        (x_value, y_value),         # Place label at end of the bar
        xytext=(0, space),          # Vertically shift label by `space`
        textcoords="offset points", # Interpret `xytext` as offset in points
        ha='center',                # Horizontally center label
        va=va)                      # Vertically align label differently for
                                    # positive and negative values.
```